# Bash cut .csv files

Tags: bash, csv, cut

I'm working with a sample .csv file 

my.csv:

```
1/2/09 6:17,Product1,1200,Mastercard,carolina,Basildon,England,United Kingdom,1/2/09 6:00,1/2/09 6:08,51.5,-1.1166667
1/2/09 4:53,Product1,1200,Visa,Betina,Parkville                   ,MO,United States,1/2/09 4:42,1/2/09 7:49,39.195,-94.68194
1/2/09 13:08,Product1,1200,Mastercard,Federica e Andrea,Astoria                     ,OR,United States,1/1/09 16:21,1/3/09 12:32,46.18806,-123.83
1/3/09 14:44,Product1,1200,Visa,Gouya,Echuca,Victoria,Australia,9/25/05 21:13,1/3/09 14:22,-36.1333333,144.75
1/4/09 12:56,Product2,3600,Visa,Gerd W ,Cahaba Heights              ,AL,United States,11/15/08 15:47,1/4/09 12:45,33.52056,-86.8025
1/4/09 13:19,Product1,1200,Visa,LAURENCE,Mickleton                   ,NJ,United States,9/24/08 15:19,1/4/09 13:04,39.79,-75.23806
1/4/09 20:11,Product1,1200,Mastercard,Fleur,Peoria                      ,IL,United States,1/3/09 9:38,1/4/09 19:45,40.69361,-89.58889
1/2/09 20:09,Product1,1200,Mastercard,adam,Martin                      ,TN,United States,1/2/09 17:43,1/4/09 20:01,36.34333,-88.85028
1/4/09 13:17,Product1,1200,Mastercard,Renee Elisabeth,Tel Aviv,Tel Aviv,Israel,1/4/09 13:03,1/4/09 22:10,32.0666667,34.7666667
1/4/09 14:11,Product1,1200,Visa,Aidan,Chatou,Ile-de-France,France,6/3/08 4:22,1/5/09 1:17,48.8833333,2.15
```

I'm trying to print out data using `cut -d"," -f-6 my.csv` but this only prints the first row: 
`1/2/09 6:17,Product1,1200,Mastercard,carolina,Basildon`


How do I get `cut` to print the entries of every row matching the delimiter/field?

Comment: can't reproduce, works fine, prints all rows

Comment: Is this a Windows file with `\r\n` as a line terminator?

Comment: Does `cut -d"," -f-6 <( tr -d '\r' < my.csv)` work ?

Comment: @WalterA Nope. That gives me `1/2/09 6:17,Product1,1200,Mastercard,carolina,Basildon`. @dawg I'm not sure. If it's of any help, I got the sample file from https://support.spatialkey.com/spatialkey-sample-csv-data/.

Comment: Not to restate the obvious, but Linux/Unix shell uses `ls` to list a directory. If you have a `dir` command, issue `type dir`, you will generally find `dir` is simply an *alias* for `ls -l`...

Comment: Please, do not replace your question with garbage. You can always delete your own question if you prefer.
I reverted the self-vandalised version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your example:

```
$ awk -F, '{print $6}' file
Basildon
Parkville                   
Astoria                     
Echuca
Cahaba Heights              
Mickleton                   
Peoria                      
Martin                      
Tel Aviv
Chatou
```

Or with `cut`:

```
$ cut -d, -f 6 file 
# same output
```

Or, for all fields up to and including the 6th:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=1;i<=6;i++) printf "%s%s", $i, i==6 ? ORS : OFS}' file
```

Or, `cut` version:

```
$ cut -d, -f-6 file
```

Comment: Thanks! 
For some reason, when running `$ awk -F, '{print $6}' my.csv` or `$ cut -d, -f 6 my.csv`, the only thing that gets printed in my terminal is `Basildon`... edit: Ahh, so when I created a new file and paste the csv, `$cud -d "," -f6` executes it just as intended. Do you know what might cause that?

Comment: Windows file? You may need to convert line endings.

Comment: The CSV format from RFC4180 defines Quotes; awk will not evaluate them correctly in other CSV files using this feature.